# jquery post undefined in firebug

Tags: javascript, jquery

On 2 of my elements in a form, I am receiving 'undefined' in firebug. I have tried to trace the error, but keep hitting a brick wall, hence the post. One of the areas with the error is in the divId block and the other is the #company in the form. I would be grateful if someone could check my code and point out my error. Thanks

```
// Function to add box

function addbox() {

    $("#boxform").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Submit a box intake request',
        width: 470,
        beforeclose: function (event, ui) {
            $("#addbox").html("");
            $("#divId").html("");

        }

    });

    $('#boxsubmit').click(function () {

        var company = $('.company').val();
        var box = $('.box').val();
        var service = $('#service').val();
        var authorised = $('.authorised').val();
        var address = $('.address').val();
        var data = 'company=' + company + '&box=' + box + '&authorised=' + authorised + '&service=' + service + '&address=' + address;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "boxesadd.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#boxform").get(0).reset();
                $('#addbox').html(data);
                //$("#form").dialog('close');
                $("#flex1").flexReload();

            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#boxform").dialog('open');

}
```

html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
    $("#company").live('change', function() { if ($(this).val()!="")
    $.get("../../getOptions.php?customer=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
    $("#divId").html(data); }); }); 
      });
</script

<form id="boxform" method="post" class="webform" name="boxform" />

        <label for="company">Select a Company:</label>
        <select name="company" id="company" />
          <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select a Company</option>
          <?php
           do {  
           ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?>"><?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?></option>
          <?php

          } 
          while ($row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust));
          $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordsetcust);
          if($rows > 0)

         {
          mysql_data_seek($Recordsetcust, 0);
          $row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust);
                    }

          ?>
          </select>

          <!--- displays the address from the change function -->
          <div id="divId"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

```
<form id="boxform" method="post" class="webform" name="boxform" />
```

to

```
<form id="boxform" method="post" class="webform" name="boxform">
```

and

```
<select name="company" id="company" />
```

to

```
<select name="company" id="company">
```

and

```
var company = $('.company').val();
```

to

```
var company = $('#company').val();
```

Comment: thanks you. How do I trace undefined for address which is in divId?

Comment: Without the markup I cant say for sure, but you may have the same problem on that one too.  In css (and jquery selectors) dot (`.`) is for class values and hash (`#`) is for id values.  You're querying for `.address`, so unless the markup has `class='address'` it won't find it.

Comment: joeshmo the address is created by php based on the script in my html code. Where can i post php script for you to view? thanks

Comment: BTW, it is an option value.  echo '<option value="address">'.$address.'</option>';

Answer (score 1):

`<select name="company" id="company" />` should be `<select name="company" id="company">`
Then form tag is also not closed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your `#boxsubmit` `click` handler, you use dot instead of hash for `#company`.

Change

```
    var company = $('.company').val();
```

to

```
    var company = $('#company').val();
```

and remove the self close `/` on non-empty elements.